# how to move the members in the VSAN prior to deleting

Tags: switch

I 'm using Cisco MDS 9120 departmental switch for configuring VSAn. Now that I noticed ,i 've to delete a VSAn .In order to do that it is advisable that i take the members in them out of that VSAN so that i can utilize them later. hOW can i do that ..i mean how do i take the ports in it out prior to deleting the VSAN . thanks in advanceg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to either wipe the VSAN and rebuild or just save the config, edit it as required, wipe the config and reapply the new one.